# Raspberry Pi 3 wifi cancellation

Tags: wifi, pi-3

Is it possible to completely disable the WiFi on the Raspberry Pi 3? Meaning no wireless connection at all for eternity?

I think the best way is just to physically cut off the antenna from the board itself, but will it damage the Raspberry?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable WiFi (wlan0) on Pi 3](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43720/disable-wifi-wlan0-on-pi-3)

Comment: @tlhIngan it's not a duplicate, because the question is different: not just disable, but make it "unable to being used/elaborated/detected"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Air-gapping the Raspberry Pi 3](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43286/air-gapping-the-raspberry-pi-3)

Answer (score 2):

In raspbian do:

```
aptitude purge firmware-brcm80211
```

This way the wireless firmware wont be loaded at boot time. In addition, it will save RAM too.

Comment: Good answer although you could "save RAM" on about the same scale by shortening your hostname ;)

Answer (score 1):

No transmitter will "like" an antenna being just cut off - it will fry for sure. Disable the built-in WiFi hardware in your OS, or - if it's a privacy concern - in your OS image disable the specific device support by VendorID/DeviceID pair, so there will be no way to detect it. If you need even more security+privacy - play with dtb-lists to prevent even an externally-built module to detect the WiFi chip and use a kernel modules signature check. But don't cut off the antenna - it's not the way it's done properly

Comment: will it disable all wave emission? I'd like to be sure there is no wave emission?

Comment: @PhilippeGachoud As far as I concern there's no WiFi chip that is emitting/active "by default", i.e. not being activated by direct-query/bios/driver/software first

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `rfkill` program to disable wlan and bluetooth on the software level. I think some chips will turn off completely, others just stop transmitting anything.

Answer (score -1):

I think that any kind of software has a backdoor, e.g. a creator of a software knows how to bypass it, or professional hackers learn how to attack "disabled" WiFi and Bluetooth computers

Therefore there's no way of 100% protect the Raspberry Pi 3, and I don't think there will be any future Raspberry Pi without wireless connectivity